# Android Get font from URL without saving

Tags: android

I have an application that draws text in a picture. And I want to use custom fonts available by link. It is necessary for the user to insert the link to the font into the EditText and the font to be loaded only in the RAM, not on the phone memory or SD card.

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can save the font on your firebase storage and let your user download the font through the link. There will be no need to download. You can directly get it.